# Android - Running applications programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, spotify

Is there way to run programs like spotify when my phone connects spesific bt device. I have bt stereo on my car and I want my phone start play music from spotify.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the BT device connecting, and then start an `Intent` to start Spotify. You'll need to figure out which Intent to start in order to activate the app.

Comment: Just to add, you cannot "drive" applications programmatically by injecting events as a fake user, but if you have an app that is set up to do things in response to intents, then you can send it one.

Comment: Yep - in general, it's not trivial to do anything beyond just starting an app. Some apps may be nice enough to detail all their supported intents on their website (or better still, on http://www.openintents.org), but unfortunately, this is extremely rare.